# Google Drive API export get empty content with application/zip MIME

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have this code:

```
// v2.2.1 Client library for Google APIs
// [https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client]

$client = new Google_Client(); 
$client->setAuthConfig(CONFIG_FILE);
$client->setScopes(array(
    Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE,
    Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_READONLY,
));
$service  = new Google_Service_Drive($client)

// Test file, Spreadsheets
$response = $service->files->get('1GDeQU7mVbipmQlPTTccmznUeJ0AgFyNrGA4TfzTgEys');

$download = $service->files->export($fileId, 'application/zip', array('alt' => 'media'));
$content = $download ->getBody()->getContents();
```

Until last week I have in `$content` the zipped html file (as written in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)), but now the variable is empty even if the `$download` object return statusCode 200 (success).

If I change `application/zip` to `application/pdf` the file is downloaded correctly (obviously in pdf format), so I think there aren't problems on file permissions.

The file is a Spreadsheets.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

---

**Edit:**

I think it's a bug, it does not even work with the [explorer APIs](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/drive/v3/drive.files.export?fileId=1GDeQU7mVbipmQlPTTccmznUeJ0AgFyNrGA4TfzTgEys&mimeType=application%252Fzip&_h=4&).

**Edit 2:**

Here is the issue on issuetracker.google.com: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79958384

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug seems to be solved, now the files are downloaded without errors.